# HTML Parsing and Dom Tree construction

Tags: html, dom, browser, html-parsing

So I have been trying to understand how **Browser Works**, and it's making my head spin. I have read few articles on it but all of them are not as clear as it should be.

Can any body please help me out to understand How browser works in detail.
Here's my understanding till now :

Consider this index.html as a reference :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css"
    <title>Browser Working</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Help me to understand this</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

So I know when I hit the server, The client will get the index.html in the **raw form (bytes of data)**.
Our Browser will try to convert this raw piece of data into character ( using the **character encoding** we have mentioned in the file, **correct if I wrong**).

After successful encoding or say character transformation of a file. It will undergo "**Tokenization Process**". And then **HTML parser** comes into to play which will **create Nodes from the tokenization process** and then linked them into the **Document-Object-tree also known as DOM**.

I want to know, when HTML parser reads/encounter **link TAG**, Will it send request to the server for css file or not ? If yes I know the same process will go on (i.e raw data -> character -> tokens -> node -> CSSOM ) and if it will make request, then Will the HTML Parser stop parsing  until the fully CSSOM will be completed ? Will the Node construction be stopped ? If node Construction is stopped, then the DOM Construction will be stopped too.

And If not, When will the Request for Css file sent to the server, I mean at which step ?
During Tokenization ? During HTML Parsing (Node Making) or during DOM Construction (When nodes are linked in the DOM). Also tell me Will the execution be stopped when request is sent at any of the above steps

Thanks

Comment: I hope this is a helpful article https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Parse